# Easiest way to convert string selection from UIPicker into UIColor?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, uipickerview

I'm practicing delegates and in my practice project I'm trying to let a user select their favorite color from a picker, and then use that color (as a UIColor) in the delegate method.

For clarity, this is my simple protocol:

```
protocol PersonDelegate {
    func makePerson(name: String, color: UIColor)
}
```

And I have an array of colors for the picker:

```
let colors = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Cyan", "White", "Black"]
```

And then an empty string variable to pass the user's choice into:

```
var favoriteColor = ""
```

My picker methods are:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return colors[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return colors.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    favoriteColor = colors[row]
}
```

And now when the done button is pressed, the delegate method is called and I need to provide a UIColor. Right now obviously it doesn't work because I'm trying to pass in a `String` when it's requiring a `UIColor`:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let name = nameTextField.text
    let myColor = favoriteColor

    personDelegate.makePerson(name: name!, color: myColor)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm wondering how I can either convert the `String` selection from the picker to `UIColor`, or perhaps take a different approach to make that unnecessary and do it another way.

EDIT: Full code so far

```
protocol PersonDelegate {
    func makePerson(name: String, color: UIColor)
}

class DelegateController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var colorPicker: UIPickerView!
var personDelegate: PersonDelegate!
let colors: [(string: String, color: UIColor)] = [("Red", .red), ("Orange", .orange), ("Yellow", .yellow), ("Green", .green), ("Blue", .blue), ("Cyan", .cyan)]
var favoriteColor: UIColor

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return colors[row].string
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return colors.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    favoriteColor = colors[row].color
}

@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let name = nameTextField.text
    let myColor = favoriteColor

    personDelegate.makePerson(name: name!, color: myColor)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `[String : UIColor]` dictionary:

```
let dict = ["Red": UIColor.red, "Green": UIColor.green, ...]
```

Then just look up the color with the string:

```
let color = dict[favoriteColor]!
```

---

Or you could make your `colors` array pair the `String` and the `UIColor`:

```
let colors: [(string: String, color: UIColor)] = [("Red", .red), ("Green", .green)]
```

Then when you need the string:

```
colors[row].string
```

and when you need the color:

```
colors[row].color
```

Comment: What do you mean by "look up the color with the string"? I changed my array and am now getting error on my picker method such as `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : UIColor]' with an index of type 'Int'` on `titleForRow` and `didSelectRow`

Comment: I confused things by naming the dictionary as `colors` since that is the name of your original array.  I changed it to `dict` to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused - taking your second approach, what would I put in my picker methods such as `didSelectRow`? `favoriteColor = colors[row].color`? And then how do I plug that into my delegate method in the `doneButtonPressed` function?

Comment: Yes.  `favoriteColor = colors[row].color`.  Then just `personDelegate.makePerson(name: name!, color: favoriteColor)`

Comment: Check my edit, I posted my full code so far. I'm getting an error on the class declaration `Class 'DelegateController' has no initializers`

Comment: Declare `var favoriteColor = UIColor.blue` instead of starting it as a String.

Comment: Ok thanks, that got rid of the error. So for future reference I always need to start that variable off with a default?

Comment: You need to give it a default value, or declare it to be *optional*.